# Dojo: how to delete/destroy a node from NodeList for real

Tags: javascript, dojo

Here I have a list of node and an identified node that want to remove from the list(both from view and also in memory).

```
var currentRow = dojo.query(this).parents("div").first()[0];
var parentDiv = dojo.query(currentRow).parents("div").first()[0];
var rowList = dojo.query(parentDiv).children();
```

The problem is,

```
dojo.destroy(currentRow);
```

only remove the `currentRow` from view, but when I loop the `rowList`, from `firebug` I can still see the size of rowList is orginal size without minus the one remove, so it seem stay in memory, so how can we remove a node from nodeList and can return the new nodeList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Destroying the node does not manipulate the `rowList` array, it just removes the node from the DOM tree. It means you have `currentRow` node *cached* in `rowList` array (and also in `currentRow` variable). DOM Nodes are JavaScript objects, when you remove them from the DOM tree they become later garbage collected by the JavaScript virtual machine, if they are not reachable.

In this case you just need to query `rowList` after (or again after) calling `dojo.destroy`:

```
var currentRow = dojo.query(this).parents("div").first()[0];
var parentDiv = dojo.query(currentRow).parents("div").first()[0];

dojo.destroy(currentRow);
currentRow = null;

var rowList = dojo.query(parentDiv).children();
```

If `currentRow` is globally reachable set it to `null`.

See it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/phusick/9MaUn/

Read more in Addy Osmani's [Writing Fast, Memory-Efficient JavaScript](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/11/05/writing-fast-memory-efficient-javascript/).